# Compare two tables from 2 different DBMS

Tags: sql, database, db2, sybase, business-intelligence

My company is preparing to migrate a datawarehouse from Sybase IQ to DB2.
They will do it internally without any third party software.

They are asking me to develop something to compare pre-migration and post-migration databases, i.e. compare schemas and datas for every table in order to perform regression testing.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel so I'd like to find a tool  which already exists, I did find a couple e.g. ApexSQLDiff, RedGate SQL Compare etc.

But there are two problems :

- Most of them don't handle Sybase IQ DBs
- None of them are free and my company is looking for something free (they would consider to pay though if it's not too expensive)

Do you have any tool that would allow me to do so ? Or any clues to help me to program something to do it ?

Regards

Comment: Sybase's (now SAP) `Data Assurance` product can compare `IQ 15.3/15.4/16.0` and `DB2 9.5/9.7/10.1`; one (obvious) downside is the product requires a licen$e ... as you'll probably find is true for any products capable of comparing large volumes of data across heterogenous systems; keep in mind that such tools typically also have the ability to generate SQL/reconciliation scripts; while designing your own **comparison** tool is relatively easy, adding SQL/reconciliation capabilities is going to add a good bit of complexity

Comment: Thank you for your response, I finally found https://www.sql-workbench.eu/ which seems to be complete enough to do what I want even if it's not perfect, it's free.